# Count the repetitions of the elements of a list

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, algorithms, linear-transformations, formal-languages

If I have a vector / list of any length, with repeating elements inside, how do I express formally the following transformation $ \overline {v} = (a, b, b, a, a, c, d) \mapsto (3,2,1,1) = \overline {u} $ where the elements of $ \overline {u} $ are "how many times the value $ a- (3) $ has been repeated, how many times it has been repeated the value $ b- (2) $ and so on? .

eg. $(3,6,3,2,2,2,2,4,9,7,77,6)\mapsto(4,2,2,1,1,1,1,1)$

(the order of the elements of $ \overline {u} $ doesn't matter)

Comment: In the last example, there are two occurrences of both $6$ and $3$, so I don't understand the result of the transformation. More in general, your transformation misses the correspondence between occurrences and elements. Is it not a problem?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, I guess a canonical ordering of the elements are assumed. $2$ occurs $4$ times. Nevertheless the resulting sequence would be $(4,2,2,1,1,1,1)$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco yes the resulting sequence is $(4,2,2,1,1,1,1)$

Comment: A list can be regarded as a function. A function on a set determines an equivalence relation on the set. An equivalence relation on a set determines a partition of the set. A partition of a set of $n$ elements determines a partition of the natural number $n.$ So the transformation $\overline{v} \mapsto \overline{u}$ can be decomposed as a chain of functions, each of which is well-recognised in mathematics. I'm not aware of standard notations for any of these functions. I believe the equivalence relation determined by a function $f$ is sometimes denoted by $\ker f,$ but even that is quite rare.

Comment: If you have some ${\bf v}=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$, maybe you can say that

$$f({\bf v})=(|\{i:v_i=v_j\}|,v_j\in\{v\in {\bf v}\},v_j\lt v_{j+1})$$

is such a transformation. I.e. if ${\bf v}=(a,b,b,a,a,c,d)$ then $\{v\in {\bf v}\}=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and

$$\begin{align}
f({\bf v})&=(|\{1,4,5\}|,|\{2,3\}|,|\{6\}|,|\{7\}|)\\&=(3,2,1,1)
\end{align}$$

as wanted.

Comment: @Vepir can you explain to me what the expression $|\{ i:v_i=v_j\}|$ means?

Comment: Idea was to for every unique element $v_j$ in ${\bf v}$ (which is the set $\{v\in {\bf v}\}$), from smallest to largest ($v_j\lt v_{j+1}$), count how many elements $v_i$ from ${\bf v}$ correspond to $v_j$ and put their indices in a set: $\{i:v_i=v_j\}$, then count the number of elements of that set ($|S|$ is the size of the set $S$.)

Comment: @Vepir thats nice, is definitely the answer. if you post it I can close the question. it would also be very interesting how to express this in the Mathematica language

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this is how construction of tuples or vectors is usually noted or if there is a better notation (or definition). $-$ How you would use it in [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) (or any other implementation in any other language), depends on the context and the problem. For example, in `python`, for your problem, I would use the `Counter` class that maps unique elements of $v$ to their frequencies (the elements of $u$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can describe the operation as first taking the multiset of values (which is formally a map from the value domain, here apparently numbers, to the natural numbers associating to each value its multiplicity of occurrence), then taking the multiset of the positive multiplicities, which multiset of positive numbers is then represented as list of those multiplicities, sorted into weakly decreasing order.

In your example the first multiset (of values) is the map sending $1\mapsto0$, $2\mapsto4$, $3\mapsto2$, $4\mapsto1$, $5\mapsto0$, $6\mapsto2$, $7\mapsto1$, $9\mapsto1$, $77\mapsto1$ and $v\mapsto0$ for all remaining values, a multiset that could also be represented as set-with-repetitions $\{\!\!\{2,2,2,2,3,3,4,6,6,7,9,77\}\!\!\}$, then the second multiset (of positive multiplicities) maps $1\mapsto 4$, $2\mapsto2$, $4\mapsto1$ (fortunately the multiplicity $0$ is exempted, as it would have infinite multiplicity, which is not normally allowed in multisets) and this multiset can be represented as $\{\!\!\{4,2,1,2,1,1,1\}\!\!\}=\{\!\!\{1,1,1,1,2,2,4\}\!\!\}$, or as described in weakly decreasing order as the sequence $(4,2,1,1,1,1)$.